# Is this an existing matrix distance/metric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, metric-spaces

I was thinking about comparing different basis transformations and came up with this distance function:

$$d(A,B)= \dfrac{||A - B||^2}{||A|| + ||B||}$$

I am using the Schatten-1-norm as the norm here (which is the sum of the singular values). A and B are matrices of the same dimensions.

I am pretty sure it is a metric, but I couldn't find it anywhere else. Does anyone know the name?
Or if it is not a metric, i would be happy to know the reasoning.

Comment: $d(A,A)\neq 0$ isn't it?

Comment: There was supposed to be a minus in the numerator, sorry.

Comment: Concerning the non-negativity, why should the sum of the singular values of the matrices be positive? Do you assume positive (semi)-definite matrices?

Comment: @nullgeppetto the Schatten-norm is a ***norm*** moreover the singular value of a matrix are always nonnegative...

Comment: @Zorah Could please provide more context.

Comment: @timmbob, ok, thanks for the clarification, but what would that mean for matrices $A$, $B$? Can they be just in $\Bbb{R}^{m\times n}$? I think that more info about matrices $A$, $B$ is indeed needed!

Comment: @nullgeppetto seems like, but that is why I'm asking Zorah for more context and details about the question.

Comment: By the way $d(0,0)$ is still not well define...

Comment: The matrices would be $n x n$ in my case. They are linear transformations from some basis into another. I basically want to compare the similarity of the transformations which are outputs from some algorithm, so I don't want to put any constraints on the rank or anything, but they are real.

Comment: Your "metric" fails the triangle inequality even for scalars: $d(1,2)+d(2,3)=\frac13+\frac15\not\ge1=d(1,3)$. (I found this counterexample via [a simple WolframAlpha query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a-b%29%5E2%2F%28%7Ca%7C%2B%7Cb%7C%29%20%2B%20%28a-c%29%5E2%2F%28%7Ca%7C%2B%7Cc%7C%29%20%3C%20%28b-c%29%5E2%2F%28%7Cb%7C%2B%7Cc%7C%29).)

Comment: @Rahul maybe you should add this as an answer.

Comment: You are right, thank you (also for the tip on WolframAlpha usage)

Comment: @Rahul: I thought I read all the comments before posting, but either I didn't or there was a flurry of comments after I started typing. If you post your answer, I'll upvote it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$
d(a, b) = \begin{cases}
  \dfrac{(a - b)^{2}}{|a| + |b|} & a \neq b, \\
  0 & a = b,
\end{cases}
$$
does not satisfy the triangle inequality, so the proposed function is not a metric even on $1 \times 1$ matrices.

Indeed, if $a = 0$, $b = \frac{1}{2}$, and $c = 1$, then
$$
d(a, b) + d(b, c) = \frac{1/4}{1/2} + \frac{1/4}{3/2}
  = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{8}{3}
  < 1 = \frac{1^{2}}{0 + 1} = d(a, c).
$$

In case this general remark is useful, it's a "bad sign" for the triangle inequality that the function
$$
f(a) = d(1, a) = \frac{(1 - a)^{2}}{1 + a}
  = -3 + a + \frac{4}{1 + a},\quad a > 0,
$$
is convex (rather than concave).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a metric I am afraid. It violates the anti symmetry property required to be a metric. What happens when A = B = $0$ (the zero matrix)? $d(A,B) = d(0,0)$ is $0/0$ not $0$.

Comment: timmbob has a more general answer.(beaten by seconds , dam slow internet).

Comment: 6 min is not exactly what I'd call "seconds", anyway our answers are wrong due to OP typo.

Comment: The limit at point 0 is still 0, if I set the other variable. So if i "define" d(0,0)=0 it is not entirely wrong, right? What would the value otherwise be? Just undefined or infinity?

Comment: If you set the limit at 0 to be 0 then you have a different function(now piece wise) entirely. But I digress , as shown above you still have the problem that the triangle inequality property doesn't hold. P.S. Our answers aren't wrong, whether it's A+B or A-B doesn't change the fact that d(0,0) is not 0;